# A better way to query MongoDB for set memberships?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, dataset, logic

Basically trying to figure out if there is a better way to do this, it's a bit clunky to say the least.

I'm trying to query my mongoDB database using three variables and I want to output a set of numbers which indicate how many items within the given sample contain certain set memberships/co-occurrences of the variables (not probabilities of co-occurrences but actual co-occurrences). Is there a simpler way to do this than just querying one by one for "A and B and C" followed by "A and B but not C" etc...?

**Example query:** Given 100 newspaper articles in the database, what are all the set memberships for occurrences of keywords A, B and C?

**Example output:** *(output in form 10,20,20,5,5,10,20,10)*

- A & B & C exist: 10
- A & B (but not C): 20
- A & C (but not B): 20
- A (but not B or C): 5
- B & C (but not A): 5
- B (but not A or C):10
- C (but not A or B): 20
- None: 10

**Edit:** Below is a sample of the type of data I am trying to query, mainly stemmed keywords:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5af2f38f8ff26c8160a864be"),
"date" : ISODate("2010-03-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
"publication" : "guardian",
"title" : "'After you Conor, age before beauty' – Ian Paisley in his own words",
"keywords" : [ 
    "queen", 
    "church", 
    "associ", 
    "scotland", 
    "intent", 
    "parti",   
    "alli", 
    "northern", 
    "secretari", 
    "age", 
    "gather", 
    "rival",  
    "unit"
],
"article_id" : ObjectId("5a72d72b257e063072ad9605")
```

}

...and the way I am currently querying the database:

```
counter = article_list.count( { $and: [{keywords: {$in: ["scotland"]}}, {keywords: {$in: ["church"]}},{keywords: {$in: ["queen"]}}] } )
outputArray.append(counter) # A & B & C

counter = article_list.count( { $and: [{keywords: {$in: ["scotland"]}}, {keywords: {$in: ["church"]}},{keywords: {$nin: ["queen"]}}] } )
outputArray.append(counter) # A & B

counter = article_list.count( { $and: [{keywords: {$in: ["scotland"]}}, {keywords: {$nin: ["church"]}},{keywords: {$in: ["queen"]}}] } )
outputArray.append(counter) # A & C

counter = article_list.count( { $and: [{keywords: {$in: ["scotland"]}}, {keywords: {$nin: ["church"]}},{keywords: {$nin: ["queen"]}}] } )
outputArray.append(counter) # ONLY A

counter = article_list.count( { $and: [{keywords: {$nin: ["scotland"]}}, {keywords: {$in: ["church"]}},{keywords: {$in: ["queen"]}}] } )
outputArray.append(counter) # B & C

counter = article_list.count( { $and: [{keywords: {$nin: ["scotland"]}}, {keywords: {$in: ["church"]}},{keywords: {$nin: ["queen"]}}] } )
outputArray.append(counter) # ONLY B

counter = article_list.count( { $and: [{keywords: {$nin: ["scotland"]}}, {keywords: {$nin: ["church"]}},{keywords: {$in: ["queen"]}}] } )
outputArray.append(counter) # ONLY C

print ', '.join(outputArray)
```

Basically just wondering if there is a better way to do this that someone can suggest, which doesn't involve looping through the queries.

Comment: It would probably be clearer for everyone and get you a more decisive answer if you showed a small sample of documents and showed by example what is actually needed to be achieved here. We've all tried to "brain dump" at the end of a day, but it's usually far clearer to show the examples rather than talk about logical conditions.

Comment: Sorry but the addition of "newspaper" is not exactly the sort of clarification people are looking for. The advise is being given that your question is unclear and you need to provide a sample as mentioned in order to give a clear picture for others. Since we are not talking about a theoretical problem, then producing data should not be an issue.

Comment: The addition of "newspaper" wasn't meant to clarify in response to your comment but was just a simple oversight in my intended text. I'm unable at the moment to upload more because I'm not at my primary workstation. I'll try to upload something more useful later.